# std::copy_n doesn't change destination vector size

Tags: c++, c++11, copy, stdvector, stl-algorithm

If I reserve some space for a vector, and then I copy some values in it with `std::copy_n()`, I get the values copied correctly and accessible, but the size of the vector is still zero. Is this the expected behaviour? Should I resize the vector instead, even if it is not as efficient?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> src, dest;

    for(double x = 0.0; x < 100.0; ++x)
        src.push_back(x);

    dest.reserve(src.size());

    std::copy_n(src.cbegin(), src.size(), dest.begin());

    std::cout << "src.size() = " << src.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dest.size() = " << dest.size() << std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << dest[i] << "  ";

}
```

Compilers tested: clang, gcc, Visual C++

Comment: I think the `reserve()` affects only the capacity, not the size.

Comment: @RawN, yes, but I expected `copy_n` to update the size.

Comment: You know that you could simply do dest=src? You know the assign function of vector?

Comment: @manni66: Yes. I oversimplified my code, but src may not be an std::vector.

Comment: @Pietro assign has an overload for iterators.

Comment: @manni66: Are `copy_n` and `operator=` equivalent under this point of view, then? Any performance/implementation differences?

Comment: @Pietro obviously they are not: operator= assigns one vector to an other, copy_n copies one range to an other. I would assume that operator= ist faster. It is definitely  safer.

vector::assign has more in common with copy_n, but it would never write outside the allocated space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but the size of the vector is still zero

`std::copy_n` won't change the size of the container, just copy the value and step the iterators; it even doesn't have any information about the container. So the code has undefined behavior, even it seems to work fine.

> Should I resize the vector instead, even if it is not as efficient?

Yes you could use `std::vector::resize` instead of `std::vector::reserve` to solve the issue. As you might have thought, it means all the elements will be constructed by `resize` firstly, then assigned by `copy_n`.

You could use [std::back_inserter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which will append elements at the end of the container by invoking the container's `push_back()` member function (i.e. construct elements directly), thus increase the container's size. e.g.

```
dest.reserve(src.size());
std::copy_n(src.cbegin(), src.size(), std::back_inserter(dest));
```

Comment: Isn't `std::back_inserter` way slower than `std::vetor::resize` and then copying?

Comment: @KamilKoczurek No. It will invoke the container's `push_back` to append the elements directly; instead of construct all the elements by `resize` and then assign them.

Comment: Right, I didn't realize that you call `std::vetor::reserve`, so there's no need to re–allocate memory, my bad.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek It's fine. Indeed, I didn't write that explicitly in first time in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The key thing to remember about standard library algorithms is that they operate on **ranges**, not containers. Containers are one of the ways that you can create ranges, but they are not the only way. Algorithms that write results into a range assume that they are writing to valid locations; they do not, and cannot, extend the range that they are writing to.

So when you call `std::copy_n` you must provide a range that's large enough to hold the result. That means setting up the range with `dest.resize(src.size());`, not just allocating memory with `dest.reserve(std.size());`.

Alternatively, you can provide a range that knows that it's attached to a container and needs to adjust the size, by calling the algorithm with `std::back_inserter(dest)` instead of `dest.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

A std::vector has a *size* and a *capacity*. It reserves some more space than necessary to make insertion faster. *reserve* enables you to specifiy that capacity, while *resize* changes the real size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your `dest` allocated memory to store elements after you called `reserve`, but it doesn't call constructors and it is actually empty, so your code leads to UB. Use `resize` to actually create those elements and then it will be ok.

```
dest.resize(src.size());
std::copy_n(src.cbegin(), src.size(), dest.begin());

std::cout << "src.size() = " << src.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "dest.size() = " << dest.size() << std::endl;

for(size_t i = 0; i < src.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << dest[i] << "  ";
```